# Mac Keyboard Command key remapping doesn't work in Terminal

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard, xmodmap

I'm using a Mac keyboard on Linux Mint 13 - Mate. I want to be able to copy/paste/cut as I done on the Mac, but on Linux with this Mac keyboard. I tried the settings I've found mentioned in several places:
Go into System -> Preferences -> Keyboard

Click on the "Layouts" tab and then click the "Layout Options" button.

Click on "Alt/Win key behavior"

Select "Control is mapped to Win keys (and the usual ctrl key).

But the problem is, while this works for LibreOffice and Geany, it messed up Terminal. Command+C which should be a COPY, acts like a control+c. How can this all be made to work?

I'm new to all this, so kind replies are most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If `Control-C` doesn't copy, `Super-C` won't either when you remap the latter to the former. Mac OS X simply has the advantage of not reusing `Ctrl` for menu commands. Check your menu items, *Edit » Copy* is probably `Ctrl-Shift-C` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Daniel. If I don't use the Click on "Alt/Win key behavior", I can remap in the Terminal program to use COPY to be SUPER+C and it works, however it only works in the Terminal program (which in this case is Terminator, if that matters).